# TypeError: Object #<Strategy> has no method 'findByUsername'

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I'm attempting to use `passport-local` as follows:

**users.js:**

```
var Users = function() {}
Users.prototype.findByUsername = function(username, cb) {
    var user = { name: username };
    cb(null, user);
};
Users.prototype.verify = function(username, password, done) {
    this.findByUsername(username, function(err, user) {
        done(null, user);
    });
};

module.exports = Users;
```

In **app.js**:

```
var Users = require('./users');
var users = new Users();

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(users.verify));
```

When I attempt to log in, I get `TypeError: Object #<Strategy> has no method 'findByUsername'`.

I'm new to Javascript (and node.js), but I've done some searching, and I think I'm using the constructor pattern correctly.

So why is `this` set to an instance of `Strategy`, rather than an instance of `Users`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(users.verify));
```

you are passing the function to LocalStrategy which changes it's context (functions are first class citizens in JavaScript). `this` no longer points to the User object but to the Strategy. Hence you need to bind your function to the Users context.

A bit of wild guess suggestion:

```
Users.prototype.verify = function(username, password, done) {
    this.findByUsername(username, function(err, user) {
        done(null, user);
    });
}.bind(Users.prototype);
```

Comment: Solved it with "new LocalStrategy(users.verify.bind(users))"